# Looking for lasem (pre-compiled mathview package for Ubuntu)

Tags: plugins, abiword

I've searched high and low, but it seem that this package simply does not exist for Ubuntu yet? (v 0.4.x) In any case, it ought to exist, because `AbiWord` requires it for its `mathview` plugin which it uses to read math stuff.

As I need to get things going (and, in particular, [bug 13716](http://bugzilla.abisource.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13716) fixed in AbiWord's MS Word importer) I built `lasem` from source, which eventually stopped `./configure` from complaining. Needless to say that this should not be necessary.